Leave cell blank until data is entered when multiplying
I have very little experience with spreadsheets and computers in general compared to, I assume, all of you.  So, if you could spell out the answer to the below question as clearly as possible, it would be greatly appreciate.
How do I keep the cell blank in the following situation?:
In cell D3, I want to use the formula =C3*.0225
Once that cell has the formula and is blank, how would I get the cells in Column D to remain blank if I want to have the same situation all the way down (i.e. for cell D4, I want to use the formula =C4*.0225 and so on)?  Would I just click the ball thing on the bottom right of cell D3 and drag down until D20 (D20 is obviously the last cell I'd need to formula to be calculated).  Thank you so very very much for sharing your expertise with me!!

when would it not be blank?

If you want the cell with the formula to remain blank while doesn't have the require input, change formula to have an IF(...)
=IF(CR<>"";C3*.0225;"")
Which simply checks whether C3 cell not empty and attempts the multiplication only if not,
otherwise sets the cell to display empty (created by the second "" - the 'empty string').
